# How the return type of intercept() is used by struts?

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I am not able to understand the concept behind the return type of `intercept()`.Is it any time related to the return type of `actionInvocationInstance.invoke()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `String`, and should be the name of a result.

It may be the result from `invoke`, or an interceptor's result that "intercepts" the action invocation, e.g., the workflow interceptor returns `"input"` on a validation error.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't related, but the [`ActionInvocation::invoke()`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionInvocation.html#invoke%28%29) can return a *result code* which is suitable to return by the interceptor's `intercept` method. It's up to you to decide which *result code* to return by the interceptor, but the *result code* type is a `String` defined as a return type by the method [`Interceptor::intercept()`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/Interceptor.html#intercept%28com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation%29). Note, that a *result code* corresponds to the result name in the action config, and a result with such name should be available to the configuration at runtime.